# Loop through li's, find parent href of image in same li and append new href to that li - for each - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, loops, attr

I have a form that generates li's with different content via Ajax. Meaning that the markup in a template just references the content of li one time.

A button that I have placed within the li tag needs to have the href value of that of the image within the same li tag.

My code I have written so far finds only the first li img's href, then assigns that as the href of ALL li's.

**I need for them to have the href of their relative img.**

**Markup:**

```
<li>
    <form name="form<venda_ref>" action="<venda_codehttp>" method="get" id="addproduct<venda_ref>form">
        <venda_inventory ref=<venda_ref>,temp=searchInvt,displayunpublished=1></form>
    <div class="CTA_btn_iCAT"><a href="" title="<venda_text id=site.link.title.more.invt>"><venda_text id=site.link.more></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

**HTML Output: --> http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/3pR9y/4/**

**jQuery used to reassign hrefs of buttons:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var iCat_href = jQuery('div.prods ul.prodsGrid li form a').attr('href');
jQuery('.CTA_btn_iCAT a').attr('href', iCat_href);
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Link to the test environment itself:

http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/uk/health-and-beauty/belvia-range/icat/6belvia

Comment: Is your HTML correct? Because I didn't find any classes like `prods` and `prodsGrid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div.prods ul.prodsGrid li').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    $('.CTA_btn_iCAT a', self).attr('href', $('form a', self).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: This only grabs the URL of the main page and assigns it to the button, not the image that it hovers over:
http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/uk/health-and-beauty/belvia-range/icat/6belvia

Comment: it grabs the anchor from the form in each li and assigns in the the button.

Basically same thing as you did above but for each li individually.

Try it in your jsfiddle you posted but remove "div.prods ul.prodsGrid" from the first selector (as you didnt post that part of the markup).

Comment: Apologies @SelfHat, our site has $ assigned to something else so pasting your code in didn't work first time. Needed to replace them with 'jQuery'. Great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('li form a').each(function(){
      var iCat_href=$(this).attr('href');  
      $(this).closest('.CTA_btn_iCAT a').attr('href', iCat_href);
    });

});
```

Comment: This only grabs the URL of the main page :(
Might be better to contextualise it:
http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/uk/health-and-beauty/belvia-range/icat/6belvia

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $anchors = jQuery('div.prods ul.prodsGrid li form a');
    jQuery('.CTA_btn_iCAT a').each(function (i, el){
        $(el).attr('href', $anchors.eq(i).attr('href')); 
    });
});
```